# Object's collection being nulled on post in Razor Pages after having been set successfully through Ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding, razor-pages

I am trying to add items dynamically to an object's list property using Razor Pages. I can successfully add one item to the list but when I try to add another item it loses the binding and says that the list property is null.

The rest of the form has regular string and int properties that are set and persist as expected. However, when I try to manipulate a list property by dynamically adding new rows using an ajax call the list gets nulled after the first (successful) attempt.

The ajax call:

```
$("#btnAdd").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            type: "POST",
            url: '?handler=AddOrderItem',
            success: function (partialView) {
                $('#orderItemsContainer').html(partialView);
            }
        });
    });
```

The PageModel method:

```
public IActionResult OnPostAddOrderItem()
    {
        CurrentSample.SampleDistributions.Add(new SampleDistributionResource());
        return Partial("SampleDistributionsPartial", CurrentSample);
    }
```

The partial view:

```
@model QBSampleGenerator.Models.Resources.CreateSample
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.SampleDistributions.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.SampleDistributions[i].DistributionAmount" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.SampleDistributions[i].DistributionAmount" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.SampleDistributions[i].DistributionAmount" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
}
```

The class definition of the CurrentSample object:

```
public class CreateSample
    {
        public int SurveyId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int SampleSize { get; set; }
        public int[] FilterIds { get; set; }
        public IList<SampleDistributionResource> SampleDistributions { get; set; }
    }
```

Let me know if I've forgotten to provide some necessary information. Many thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Could you provide the model of `CurrentSample` and `CreateSample`?

Comment: Certainly @Michelle, CurrentSample is a bound property and an instantiation of the CreateSample class. I've included the information in the above post.

Comment: You got wrong here :      `CurrentSample.SampleDistributions.Add(new SampleDistributionResource());`

Comment: What is the error though? I've checked your answer but if I were to change my BoundProperty to static I get the following error: "Member 'CreateModel.CurrentSample' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"

Comment: How do you declare `CurrentSample`? Please post the detail of `CurrentSample`.

Comment: It seems you didn't  `new SampleDistributions()` when before you `Add()`

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `CurrentSample` after `Add()`. Here I set `CurrentSample` is `static`.

```
    private  static CreateSample CurrentSample = new CreateSample();

    [HttpPost("/AddOrderItem")]
    public IActionResult OnPostAddOrderItem()
    {
        CurrentSample.SampleDistributions.Add(new SampleDistributionResource());
        return PartialView("SampleDistributionsPartial", CurrentSample);
    }
```

> Codes of Model

```
    public class SampleDistributionResource
    {
        public SampleDistributionResource() { DistributionAmount = 0; }

        public int DistributionAmount { get; set; }
    }

    public class CreateSample
    {

        public int SurveyId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int SampleSize { get; set; }
        public int[] FilterIds { get; set; }
        public IList<SampleDistributionResource> SampleDistributions { get; set; }

        public CreateSample() { SampleDistributions = new List<SampleDistributionResource>(); }

    }
```

> Screenshots of test

[image]

Comment: Hi, @bjorkvalle, please let us know if you have  updated information on this issue.